# Does an e var created on every event that occur?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, callback, addeventlistener

Im currently learning the concept of a callback function.
From what I understood, a function that had been sent to another function as a varaible is called callback function, and in addition, it waits untill something happens so it will be executed.

An attempt to explain how the eventListener works from inside was [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlujS.png)

The example here shows that every event that occur create an `event` var and if the type of the event is identical to the event I asked then it will execute the callback function.

My question is if I undertood it correctly.
Every event that occurs creates a var?
or only if I listen for this event the var is created.

Comment: No, events exists even if there are no listeners. There is no way for the event to know whether there are listeners for it or not - it just fires and that will trigger any listeners there are.

Comment: The variable is part of the definition of the listener function. If there's no listener, there's no event variable.

Comment: There's still an event, but nothing is done with it.

Comment: ok, but the var is created either way?
and the example in the picture is correct?